# Combining string with JSON object to return the data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that I need to retrieve a value from.

This is the object reference that works...gets the data I need.

```
dataJSON.companies[0].fields.Internet.length
```

What I need to do is somehow evaluate the object with a string variable added in. Something like...

```
var mediaType = 'Internet'; 
dataJSON.companies[0].fields+mediaType+.length;
```

This there any way to do this? I'm stumped.

Comment: You could use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

Comment: Try: `dataJSON.companies[0].fields[mediaType].length;`

Comment: Thank you Teemu! That worked. I'm new to working with JSON objects in JS.

Comment: That's actually not a JSON object, it's just an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the square brackets access notation when you do not know the name of the property until runtime.

var mediaType = 'Internet'; 
dataJSON.companies[0].fields[mediaType].length;

You can access the members of an object with either dot notation or square brackets notation.

e.g.

```
var result = myobject.propertname;
```

or

```
var result = myobject["propertyname"];
```